# How to figure out whether a Masters degree is a "Professional" or "Research" degree?

Tags: masters

How to figure out whether a university-program is offering Professional Masters degree  or "Research" Masters degree?

Are all taught Masters degree programs professional programs?

Comment: You've got at least three questions there. You've been on StackExchange long enough to know that the etiquette is to ask one question at a time.

Comment: Actually, there are really only two questions: the first two could be considered one related question, while the second two are related. Still one too many, but not as bad as you think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is that **research** MS degrees require a thesis, which describes the student's **research**, while professional/taught MS degrees do not.

There are several secondary differences as well.  Professional/taught MS programs are cash cows; their enrollments are generally higher, their admissions criteria are generally lower, they almost never offer financial support, and students are generally treated like cattle.  Research MS programs generally have smaller enrollment, because the students require more individual attention, and therefore higher admission standards; some research MS programs offer financial support in the form of assistantships or even fellowships.  In many departments, there is an easy transition from a research MS program into the PhD program; transitioning from a professional/taught MS program into a PhD program is almost impossible.

Of course, these answers are very crude approximations.  The actual difference will vary significantly between departments.